# Get Simple Product Id's in Cart

Tags: cart, product-attribute

I need to add some code to cart.phtml to get the product ID's of the item in the cart.  I need the ID's of the simple products.  So far I have this:

```
  <?php $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
$productIds = "";
foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item):
    if(!$item->getParentItemId()) continue; // Don't output config Id's
    if (strlen($productIds)==0){
        $productIds = "'".$item->getProductId()."'";
    }
    else{
        $productIds = $productIds.",'".$item->getProductId()."'";
    }
endforeach;?>
```

This currently shows the ID's of Simple Products that are part of a configurable product.  The problem is if the product is a simple product that isn't part of a configurable product it's ID doesn't get shown.

Any ideas how to get these to show also?

Comment: `$cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();` use this to get item

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
$productIds = array();
foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
  if($item->getProductType()=='simple') {
    $productIds[] = $item->getProductId();  
  }
}
print_r($productIds);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use getAllVisibleItems() method instead of getAllItems()

```
<?php
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
$productIds = array();


/** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item $item */
foreach($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
    $productIds[] = $item->getProductId();
}

var_dump($productIds);
?>
```

Comment: The problem with this is it then shows the ID for the configurable product and not the ID for the child product.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
foreach ($cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
    $productId = $item->getProduct()->getId();
    if ($option = $item->getOptionByCode('simple_product')) {
        $productId = $option->getProduct()->getId();
    }
    $productIds[] = $productId;
}
```